# wpf datagrid Ienumerable returning null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ienumerable

Using C#.NET4.5, MS Visual Studio 2012, WPF.

Hi guys got some code here that giving me null.  This code was a previous solution that I tried.  I received no errors but never tested through it since today when I found I debugged there rows were null.

Heres the code:

1st I throw my data I collected from SQL to a datatable and threw it into my datagrid...

```
 private void LoadPareto(string pg)
 {
     DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
     tbl = mysqlq.SQL_GetPareto(pg);
     paretogrid.ItemsSource = tbl.AsDataView();
     // InsertColumns();
     ShowArrows();
 }
```

2nd set up binding in XAML...

```
<DataGrid Name ="paretogrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

3rd I created an Ienumerable...

```
public IEnumerable<System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow> GetDataGridRow(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsource = grid.ItemsSource as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow; // null?
        if (null != row) yield return row;
    }
}
```

Then I call it in this method...

```
private void ShowArrows()
{
    var rows = GetDataGridRow(paretogrid); // fetching null?

    foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
    {
        DataRowView rv = (DataRowView)r.Item;
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in paretogrid.Columns)
        {
            if (column.GetCellContent(r) is TextBlock)
            {
                TextBlock cellcontent = column.GetCellContent(r) as TextBlock;
                MessageBox.Show(cellcontent.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the Problem I have is in the Ienumerbale I see my item source contains 12007 records which is perfect. Yet when I step through I find ...

```
var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
```

Is returning null which my "if" statement find it as a false so skips the yield.
So of course, when i go to step through the foreach loop in "showarrows" method It doesnt bother since there's null.

So where am I going wrong? am I missing something?

Thanks in advance guys n girls!

Comment: hasnt got anything to do with my table being set to a "asdataview" does it?

Comment: You are setting the `ItemsSource` both in the code-behind and xaml. Could you try removing the binding part?

Comment: ahhhh I see, yes i took part of a code behind answer and part of an XMAL answer. I'll try taking out the XAML see whats happens

Comment: nope removed the binding in XAML and no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataGrid` has't yet updated when you're getting the rows. A solution would be to `paretogrid.UpdateLayout()` right after you set the `ItemsSource`.

Note, that this is not really good to mix the data and UI code. What you're trying to do could've probably been done in XAML, and you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: thats it! thats what also confused me debugging too! thanks for that!.  yes All i keep getting told is mvvm and never access controls direct. But to be honest I haven't got a clue what mvvm is and all I've ever coded is Winforms so for the time being i'm trying to blend into WPF slow, then when I'm used to the changes and xaml i can then start to look how to really utilize WPFs mvvm